# Create a class function that is called whenever another class function is called Python

Tags: python

I'd like to have a class that contains a function that is called whenever another class function is called. And the tricky part is that I'd like this to work for derived classes.

Let's say:

```
def class A:
  def __init__(self):
    pass
  def b(self):
    print("Hello")
```

and

```
def class B(A):
  def __special_method__(self):
    print("Before Hello")
```

And calling object.b() would print

```
Before Hello
Hello
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Catch "before/after function call" events for all functions in class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25828864/catch-before-after-function-call-events-for-all-functions-in-class)

Comment: Oh damn thanks Adam! I think a decorator could help, yes.